# Remove / hide the Bing map offline message when offline

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps

I'm developing a Windows Phone app that uses the older WP7 Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map / Bing Map control.

The map tiles are being served up from a local source so the app doesn't not need a network connection to work. Unfortunately the map control insists on showing an "Unable to contact Server. Please try again later." message over the map when offline.

Does anyone know of a method to remove / hide this message?

Just in case you're curious - I'm developing a WP8 app but using the depreciated WP7 Bing map control as the new WP8 map control provides no method for replacing the Bing base map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think this may suits you better:

```
void YourPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            m_Map.ZoomLevel = 11;          
            m_Map.LayoutUpdated += m_Map_LayoutUpdated; 
        }

        void m_Map_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isRemoved) 
            {
                RemoveOverlayTextBlock();
            }
        }

        void  RemoveOverlayTextBlock()
        {             
            var textBlock = m_Map.DescendantsAndSelf.OfType<TextBlock>()
                           .SingleOrDefault(d => d.Text.Contains("Invalid Credentials") ||
                                                 d.Text.Contains("Unable to contact Server"));
            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                var parentBorder = textBlock.Parent as Border;
                if (parentBorder != null)
                {
                    parentBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                isRemoved = true;   
            }
       }
```

You have to include a class `LinqToVisualTree` witch can be [downloaded from here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/LinqToTree.zip).
And here is the [original post](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2012/03/removing-invalid-credentials-message.html)

Comment: BTW: I changed the TextBlock selection criteria to avoid any possible localization string issues (as can't assume user is English). My code: TextBlock textBlock = Map.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<TextBlock>().SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == "ErrorMessage");

Answer (score 0):

You can either handle the `LoadingError` event per instance or extend the `Map` control yourself as described in [this post](http://guinnesslee.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/how-to-remove-unable-to-connect-to-server-please-try-again-error-in-bing-maps-control-in-wp7/). You can then remove the layer than contains the error message so that it's not shown to the user.

```
public partial class CachedMap : Map
{
    public CachedMap() : base()
    {
        base.LoadingError += (s, e) =>
        {
            base.RootLayer.Children.RemoveAt(5);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old thread, but anyways...

You can listen for `LoadingError` event as suggested @keyboardP, search for `LoadingErrorMessage` control in visual tree and simply hide it.

```
Map.LoadingError += MapOnLoadingError;

private void MapOnLoadingError(object sender, LoadingErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var errorMessage = Map.FindChildOfType<LoadingErrorMessage>();
    errorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Yay, I found my own answer 2 years later